# Rewrite array recursive function with recursive output in middle

Tags: arrays, recursion, tail-recursion

How can I rewrite this function with tail-recursion?  I don't know if it's possible because the recursive call needs to be applied in the center of the array.

```js
const weave = array =>
  array.length <= 2
    ? array
    : [ array[0], ...weave(array.slice(2)), array[1] ]
```

I wrote a function that finds the factor pairs of a number, where the pairs are of the form `[ [1, x], [2, x/2], ... ]` (assuming `x` is even, in this case).  I want to flatten the array and sort it in `O(n)` time.

```js
const getFactors = x => weave(getFactorPairs(x).flat())
```

**Note**: This is purely for my edification.  Both the function above and `array.flat().sort()` are perfectly performant enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In true Stack-Overflow-as-rubber-duck fashion, the solution became obvious while writing my best attempt at an answer within the question, so obvious that I almost didn't bother posting.

```js
const weave = (array, pre = [], post = []) =>
  array.length <= 2
    ? [ ...pre, ...array, ...post ]
    : weave(
        array.slice(2),
        [ ...pre, array[0] ], 
        [ array[1], ...post ]
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use [continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style). This technique is commonly used to achieve a tail-call in recursive forms.

```js
const identity = x =>
  x

const weave = (a, then = identity) =>
  a.length < 2
    ? then(a)
    : weave(a.slice(2), r => then([a[0], ...r, a[1]]))
      
console.log(weave("abcdefg")) // [a,c,e,g,f,d,b]
weave("abcdefg", console.log) // [a,c,e,g,f,d,b]
```

The [Trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing))  technique mentioned in the comments can be implemented in various ways. This example is modelled after Clojure's [loop/recur](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/loop) trampoline interface.

Here it is applied to your code. I traded array input for string so the output can be visualized more easily. `weave` processes a 1 million character string in less than 150ms.

```js
function recur(...values) {
  return Object.assign(values, {recur})
}

function loop(f) {
  let result = f()
  while (result?.recur === recur)
    result = f(...result)
  return result
}

const weave = (input = []) =>
  loop((a = input, pre = "", post = "") =>
    a.length < 2
      ? pre + a + post
      : recur(a.slice(2), pre+a[0], a[1]+post))
      
console.time("weave 1M")
document.write(weave(`<  >  <  >`.repeat(100000)))
console.timeEnd("weave 1M")
```

Comment: Won't that create closure for the `r => ...` function containing both `then` and `a`, defeating the memory efficiency purpose of tail-recursion?

Comment: Tail call optimization actually has nothing to do with recursion or memory efficiency - it only means that a tail call will not grow the _stack_. Continuation-passing style trades limited stack space for freely available memory space and can be applied to *any* code to make it stack-safe. The technique in your answer is a valid approach but will not work for all programs. In reality JavaScript does not support tail call optimization thus both codes in these answers is not actually stack-safe. Using a [trampoline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trampoline_(computing)) is the final step needed.

Comment: @dx_over_dt I added a trampoline example in the answer.